# PackageManagement\Install-Package : No match was found for the specified search criteria and module name SitecoreInstallFramework

Tags: powershell-5.0, sitecore9

I am getting below error while installing sitecore framework, I have register sitecore repository with https://sitecore.myget.org/F/sc-powershell/api/v2 source location.

I am using powershell 5.1
installing sitecore 9.0

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please check the `SitecoreInstallFramework` in installed and present at `C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules`. If not install and import it.

You can also install it manually if facing issue installing it through `sitecore.myget`.

### Installing the Framework Manually

As an alternative to using the MyGet feed you can also install it manually. The Sitecore Installation Framework is also provided as a zip download. But if you manually install the Sitecore Installation Framework, you must first download and install the Sitecore Fundamentals package.

You can download the Sitecore Fundamentals and the Sitecore Installation Framework packages from the Sitecore Developer site. Both downloads are available on the page with the latest version of the platform.

To install both modules you will need to extract the packages and copy the files.

- Extract the Sitecore Fundamentals.ZIP package to the following folder:
  C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreFundamentals
- Extract the Sitecore Install Framework.ZIP package to the following folder:
  C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreInstallFramework

Please refer:- https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/technical-marketing/posts/installing-sitecore-9_3a00_-install-the-sitecore-installation-framework-module